# Pytorch memory profiler returns high CPU memory for empty

Tags: python, pytorch

When I run the pytorch memory profiler it returns the following:

```
Name                       Self CPU total %  Self CPU total   CPU total %      CPU total        CPU time avg     CPU Mem          Self CPU Mem     CUDA Mem         Self CUDA Mem    Number of Calls  
-------------------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  
empty                      1.11%            443.155ms        100.19%          39.822s          1.851ms          25.95 Gb         7.98 Gb          0 b              0 b
```

This ´empty´ is taking up a lot of memory (more than anything else in the network). I wonder whether this is expected behaviour, or a sign that there are a lot of empty tensors taking up memory, without being useful?

If so, where should I start looking for the culprits?